# Tizen Store sharing published apps

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Is there a way to share a Tizen app published on the Tizen Store? Google Play Store and iOS App Store provides web interfaces to search for apps, and the store listing of an app has a dedicated URL.

The [Tizen store](http://www.tizenstore.com/main/getMain.as) does not seem to have a search option to find a published app. Moreover, the listings for only a few categories of apps can be viewed. Is it possible to share an app listing on the Tizen store via a specific URL?

Comment: As far as I know, currently this functionality is unavailable(share a Tizen app published). You may use links like YouTube to publicize your app.

Comment: Yes, I raised a query on the seller store account and got a response confirming that this is not available. It is really a hurdle in publicizing apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They added support for browsing the store via the web a few days ago. Head over to tizenstore.com and pull up your app to see the link. If you know the ContentID you can easily build the link.

The pattern looks like the following

https://www.tizenstore.com/main/getDetail.as?contentId={yourContentIdHere}

Of course you will need to place your own content ID there. A sample of a working one would be https://www.tizenstore.com/main/getDetail.as?contentId=000000085875

Comment: Thanks for updating!

Answer (score 0):

As far i know, **Tizen App Store** is opened as web interface like [**Google Play Store**](https://play.google.com/store) and [**Apple App store**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8). Visit [here](https://www.tizenstore.com/).